# Why doesn't Scala need to be installed for spark deployment?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark is developed by Scala. Theoretically, Scala needs to be installed. However, spark deployment does not need to install Scala. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Spark requires a Java installation and Scala runs on a JVM, so having Java is enough.

Answer (score 0):

When you develop a spark application using Scala , you will be packaging all the dependencies inside a Uber jar ,. This Uber jar can include all dependencies which you have used in your application directly or indirectly . Now this assembled jar can be deployed on any machine which has a correct Java installation . That is why you don't need anything else .